# Change raster cell size while keeping attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.4, aggregation, raster-attribute-table

I have a raster with a cell size of 1 and I want to increase the cell size to 5 so I use the `Aggregate()` function in ArcMap 10.4.

The problem I'm seeing is that after processing I lose the desired Attribute Column from my original raster and am left with only the Value field.  The output 'dg100' drops 'FEET_NUM' attribute from the input 'eba_100y' raster value attribute table.

Is there a way to modify the cell size of a raster while keeping all attributes?

Here are the parameters used for `Aggregate()`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is to build an attribute table for your aggregated raster (5 meter), join it to your older, 1 meter resolution raster, and create and populate the fields in your aggregated raster with the 1 meter raster attribute values.

To do this, run the Build Raster Attribute Table tool on your aggregated raster. (If your pixel type is floating point or double precision, run the Int tool to convert them to integers.) A value field in your new attribute table should match those of your original, 1 meter raster. Use these two fields to join the two attribute tables. Then add the fields you need and use the joined table to populate them.